# Rebuild LIBS/DLL everytime I want to run the debugger

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have converted a solution from Visual Studio 2008 to 2012.  It builds correctly, but every time I attempt to run the EXE in debug mode, it tells me that some of the lib files are out of date and wants to recompile them.  I am not sure where the problem is.

The solution contains - 1 exe, 1 DLL and 7 LIBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem.  Each project had a file included that was not available.  Once I removed them, complies and runs with no problems.